# DNAT to another hidden port on same host

Tags: iptables, firewall, nat, ufw

I am hoping to use iptables to silently redirect incoming traffic arriving at a privileged port on the public eth interface (public IPv4 address) to a hidden unprivileged port on the same ubuntu box. The ufw firewall is active. There are other options, of course, such as capabilities, or a privileged process copying traffic to the unprivileged port, or a privileged process dropping its privs after bind, etc, but to me at least iptables seems to be the most appealing.

The dummy interface solution in [DNAT to 127.0.0.1 with iptables / Destination access control for transparent SOCKS proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/351816/dnat-to-127-0-0-1-with-iptables-destination-access-control-for-transparent-soc) would be perfect for me (once I insert an extra 'dev' keyword into the ip add addr... command). Except for one thing:

- I must open the firewall up for incoming traffic to the IP of the dummy interface on the hidden port

As far as I can see, this allows others to send incoming traffic directly to that IP:port, should they be able to guess the roughly 40 bits of hidden info (a private IPv4 address + a port).

Is there a solution where no outside traffic can reach that hidden port, unless the original dest IP is the public IP of the box, and the dest port is the privileged port?

---

[In everyday terms, the dummy interface solution is like having my buddy come to my club, and telling him that here is a VIP pass, take it to the back entrance, and the bouncer will let you in. He will get in, sure, but anyone else may try to fool the bouncer with a fake pass. Can I instead escort my buddy to the back entrance, tell the bouncer he is good, and walk in with him? In other words, can I mark this NATted packet somehow that the firewall rules are bypassed on it?]

Comment: UFW always allows connections to localhost, so you shouldn't need to do that. Did you actually try it first?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. THe packet I need to get to the hidden port originates from outside. Most online "solutions" redirect these to another port, but that is not a real solution because then you have to open that other port on the firewall (IP stays same, so the new port is public). The only real solution I have seen so far is what I linked to. Which is DNAT to a dummy interface on the same box. Except, that still leaves a hole on the firewall, albeit one that is harder to find. The question is whether one can eliminate that hole.

Comment: Huh? DNAT to a dummy interface? No, you would DNAT to localhost.

Comment: E.g., if you redirect port 80 on host 1.2.3.4 to port 8080 on dummy interface 10.11.12.13, then you would do
```*nat
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.11.12.13:8080``` (cannot format lines here for some reason)

Comment: DNAT to localhost (127.0.0.1) to/from outside is dropped by the kernel. It is possible to enable it but that creates a bigger security hole than the one I am trying to close. Or a potentially bigger one.

Comment: It could be, though, that my assumption that packets from outside to a private address would actually make it there is wrong... and then the whole issue is moot. It is just too hard to test that on my current network :/

Comment: Oh, you're right. You have to use the REDIRECT target, not DNAT.

Comment: Have the same problem, I want to redirect 80 to 8080, but I don't want 8080 to be open public. Currently I just do the *nat PREROUTING  -j REDIRECT to 8080. I have to also have an ufw rule to then open 8080 or the redirected packets won't arrive, but as soon as I open it, packets destined directly to 8080 also are allowed (of course..). Is the MARK stuff the only way you found to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime I learned that one CAN mark packets (see, e.g., [How to set mark on packet when forwarding it in nat prerouting table?](https://serverfault.com/questions/514116/how-to-set-mark-on-packet-when-forwarding-it-in-nat-prerouting-table)), and also learned more about which iptables operations are applied when (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-deep-dive-into-iptables-and-netfilter-architecture). With these the solution is straightforward:

1. in /etc/ufw/before.rules, add a MANGLE rule:

```
*mangle
-F
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x401
COMMIT
```

2. in the same file insert a redirect into the NAT table rules (*nat section) with the line

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

3. and finally, insert into the ufw-before-input chain of the FILTER table (*filter section) with the line

```
-A ufw-before-input -m mark --mark 0x401 -j ACCEPT
```

4. restart ufw

```
services ufw restart
```

---

There is no need to open any ports, incoming packets to 1.2.3.4:80 get redirected to 1.2.3.4:8080 and are explicitly greenlighted through the firewall. The time order of iptables operations on the packet is: mark, redirect, let through.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the dummy interface and REDIRECT such traffic to the localhost IP address.

In the nat table:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Then you tell ufw to allow traffic to that port, but only destined to the localhost IP address.

```
sudo ufw allow to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 proto tcp
```

Comment: That redirect does not work. The redirected packet preserves dest ip, so you need to listen on the original interface at the new port - AND - have that port wide open on the firewall (then it works, confirmed). This is definitely not what I am after.

Comment: This way need to open both 80 and 8080 ports on ufw ! that is not a good solution, any workaround that on that way port 8080 does not needed to open on ufw ?